# How to populate form with attributes from a different object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

How can I get the `current_user`'s name to show in `text_field :name` under **duels/_dueler_fields**?

**DuelsController**

```
def new
  @duel = Duel.new
  @duel.duelers << Dueler.new(user: current_user)
end
```

**rails c**

```
pry(main)> Duel.last
 id: 20,
 consequence: "Run naked lap",
pry(main)> Dueler.last
 id: 34,
 user_id: 78,
 challenge_id: 295,
 duel_id: 20,
pry(main)> User.find(78)
 id: 78,
 name: "Anthony" # How to get User's name?
```

**duels/_form**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@duel) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :duelers do |dueler| %>
    <%= render 'dueler_fields', :f => dueler %>
  <% end %>

  The loser(s) will <%= f.text_field :consequence, placeholder: "Enter Consequence" %>.

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

**duels/_dueler_fields**

```
<%= f.number_field :user_id, placeholder: "Enter User" %>. # This will give the correct id number, but I tried setting it to text_field :name. That didn't work
```

Answer (score 1):

From your description, it looks like what you want isn't quite what you're doing; using `fields_for` will allow you to create new instances of the associated models, but it seems that you want to only link it to an existing instance.

If that's the case, try the following:

**duels/_form**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@duel) do |f| %>
  <%= f.association :user, input_html: {value: current_user.id} %>

  The loser(s) will <%= f.input :consequence, placeholder: "Enter Consequence" %>.

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Using `f.association` should automatically generate a dropdown list containing all available users and render their objects using the `to_s` method of the appropriate model (in this case, `User`)

Because of that, you'll also need to ensure there's a method in the `User` model to override `to_s` to something sensible, e.g.

**models/user**

```
def to_s
  name
end
```

Alternatively, if you just want to put in a static text field showing the current user's name and not allow it to be edited, you could do the following:

**duels/_form**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@duel) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :user_id, as: :hidden, input_html: {value: current_user.id} %>
  <label>User</label><p><%= current_user.name %></p>

  The loser(s) will <%= f.input :consequence, placeholder: "Enter Consequence" %>.

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks bdx for the help! Your first suggestion gives the error `undefined method 'user_id' for #<Duel:0x007fece24764a0>` And yea I'm trying to get the name of the `current_user` to appear in the `text_field` instead of the `id`. Sorry for the late reply!

Comment: I made an assumption about your model as well which may well not be the case then. Please check that your Duel model has the association `belongs_to :user`.

Comment: Also, if you're set on having the `current_user`'s name appear in a text field rather than a select box, the above wont' work for you either. That would require either modifying the controller to do a lookup based on the user's name and then putting their user_id into the `@duel`, or using a custom control which updates a hidden `user_id` input field in the HTML by doing what I imagine would be a live lookup on the name being entered.